# How can I use Kalman Filter formulation for inferring the probability of system failure?

Tags: kalman-filter

I want to use the Kalman filter to sense the state of a machine. The machine could be either working or damaged. I'm trying to infer the probability of the machine working, given observations from multiple independent sensors.

I'm able to formulate the problem using Bayes' Filter (discrete formulation). I'm curious to see if I can formulate the same problem leveraging distributions so that I can estimate confidence in my predictions rather than a deterministic value (i.e., 90% prob. of working v/s a distribution).

Most Kalman Filter examples in literature infer the state/location of a system/entity in an unbounded space (i.e., location) leveraging variables represented using normal distributions. Since the state of my system is bounded (i.e., 0-100%), what is the right (and mathematically elegant) approach to using Kalman Filter?

Comment: Hello, what are the outputs of your sensors? Is it continuous values or binomial?

Comment: They are binomial. They sense if a machine is working (state = 1) or not working (state = 0).

Comment: But, the observations are imperfect. Currently, I encode the uncertainty as using deterministic likelihood values (i.e., P(sensor reports working | machine working) = 0.8). I want to move from a deterministic to a distribution domain.

Comment: You could try applying non-linearity to the machine state: $z_t=f(z_{t-1})$ and use the Extended or Unscented Kalman Filter. The non linearity $f(\cdot)$ can be a sigmoid function so that $z\in (0,1)$ which you can interpret as percentage